# Select Child nodes when parent is also selected in JSTREE

Tags: jstree

I am having difficulties by selecting child nodes when parent is also selected , also would like to open subfolders and select all childs (not sure if im making it clear) so I have know how to get all the child nodes by:

```
selected_nodes = $("#demo").jstree("get_selected", null, true); 
var tree = jQuery.jstree._reference('#demo'); 
var children = tree._get_children(selected_nodes);
```

### but doest really select or open child folder and nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on this Idea.. now im just doing ajax requests to load the childs and receive a json object, and from there i can see if its a file or directory, if its a directory again another request and like this i have the whole structure

Answer (score 2):

This might not be what OP wanted but on JSTree 3.3. I used this to open all nodes under a selected parent.

```
$(treeContainer).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
            return data.instance.open_all(data.node);
        });
```

Comment: This works and can be used as follows:
 $(treeContainer).bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
                            data.instance.select_node(data.node.children);
                        });

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn on two_state checkboxes to allow parent and child nodes to be selected indepentently. Below I've configured the "two_state" parameter for the checkbox plugin:

```
$("#docTree").jstree({
    "themes": {
        "theme": "classic",
        "url": "jstree/themes/classic/style.css"
    },
    "plugins": ["themes", "ui", "checkbox", "json_data"],
    "checkbox": { "two_state" : true }
})
```

Check documentation here: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/checkbox

Comment: Thanks Andreas, but i gave up on this idea... I had checkbox working before, but its not exactly what I want

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly you want to select all of the lowest descendants in a jsTree (the files) when one of their parents (the folders) have been selected.

Unfortunately I haven't found a more direct approach than the one below. I'm using jsTree 3.1.1 and managed to solve this problem using the following:

```
var $demo = $("#demo");
var nodes =  $demo.jstree("get_top_selected", true);

//Selects all of the children of each selected node including folders
if(nodes.length > 0){
    nodes.forEach(function(node, i){
        $demo.jstree("select_node", node.children_d, true, false);
    });
}

var fileNodes = $demo.jstree("get_bottom_selected", false);

//We now need to deselect everything and only select the file nodes
$demo.jstree("deselect_all", true);
$demo.jstree("select_node", fileNodes, true, false);
```

The above code allows the user to "select" multiple folders and have those files selected.

The parameter with the value `true` for the `"get_top_selected"` function returns the full node instead of just ID's. This lets you get access to the node's children.

Function `"select_node"` takes three parameters. The first is the nodes to select (in this case the descendants of the current parent node). If the second parameter is set to true it prevents the `changed.jstree` event from firing for each selected node. The third parameter is set to `false` as setting to `true` prevents the children folders from opening.

The function `"get_bottom_selected"` only returns a node if it has both been selected **and** it itself does not have any children. As we are now only interested in the node ID's we can pass the parameter false (or omit it completely).

Passing a parameter of `true` to the function `"deselect_all"` again prevents the `changed.jstree` event from firing.

If you want to check out the jsTree API docs you can find them [here](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?q=select). That list is filtered to only include the select functions and events. A full list of the API can be found [here](https://www.jstree.com/api/).

I hope this helps but let me know if you require further clarification on any of the code ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
select all child nodes when parent selected ,
         $(data.rslt.obj).find("li").each( function( idx, listItem ) {
             var child = $(listItem); // child object
             $.jstree._reference("#associateRightHandTree").check_node(child);
         });

unselect all child nodes when parent unselected ,
        $(data.rslt.obj).find("li").each( function( idx, listItem ) {
            var child = $(listItem); // child object
            $.jstree._reference("#associateRightHandTree").uncheck_node(child);
        });
```